# mysql innodb_memcache plugin error in replication

Tags: mysql

I start using mysql 5.6 for innodb_memcache plugins , everything is working fine till I configured master-slave replication.
    two things puzzle me while configured it with master-slave.
    Note below are lines which I enabled for memcache in my.cnf

```
daemon_memcached_w_batch_size=25  
daemon_memcached_option='-v -m 1048'
```

1. when i am not using `innodb_api_enable_binlog=1` in my.cnf
   insert / update through memcache prompt (telnet localhost 11211) innodb_memcache table     doesnot replicated,but saved in table(access through memcache prompt/sql prompt).
   when i am doing this thing from sql prompt everything works fine ,data get replicated.
   don't knew how mysql replicate data without save it in binary logs.
2. when i enable `innodb_api_enable_binlog=1` in my.cnf
   insert record from sql / memcache prompt all replicated to slave server,but problem is     when i am updating records using memcache prompt it throws below error.
   Connection closed by foreign host
   and data doesnot save in table .
   now i dont know what to do, as i am plan to using mysql 5.6 in production but due to     this problem i am unable to do this up gradation.

Comment: Please describe your problem in more detail. On what server did you activate memcache? Both? Which servers my.cnf did you put `innodb_api_enable_binlog` into? Which server did you try to query or update via memcache? Please edit your original post to include more details.

Comment: Hi ,  on master slave conf , I enable memcache plugin on master server , for innodb_api_enable_binlog obvious it has been enabled on master my.cnf and for memcache / query obvious i am using master server. hope you get all information.

Comment: even I make daemon_memcached_w_batch_size=1 , still i am facing  same issue

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this site](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-memcached-troubleshoot.html)? It says you should add `-vvv` (not just `-v`) to the parameters and then should take a look at the MySQL error file. Maybe this provides additional information.

Comment: Furthermore: Do you use the most current minor version of 5.6?

Comment: i am using 5.6.16-log

Comment: Hi GhostGambler,  i tried -vvv and found below error 

10:23:54 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Comment: Did you compile server or client by yourself? You should check that all libs you used for compiling (or all packages, if you used e.g. the experimental branch of debian) have been installed in the same version.

Comment: Hi , i downloaded binaries files and used it , i am using CentOS release 6.5 .

Comment: is there any way to know which binary file is corrupted

Comment: None, which I know of. I also would not expect one to be corrupted, but more likely you are using libraries with versions which are not compatible. Maybe it's easiest to reinstall server and client and all libraries again and this time take a close look on which versions are installed and compiled against.

Comment: Hi ,  I downloaded binaries file of server and clients and all O.S lib installed through rpm. is this  is lib version mismatch issue ?  I installed it on couple of  machines and facing same issue on all machines.

Comment: I do not know. I neither know what exactly you have installed, nor is clear if this is really an issue concerning version incompatibility. It could also be a broken executable or a bug. Maybe you should better open a [bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/).

Comment: few machine i installed mysql through rpm package too ,below are details  rpm -qa | grep -i mysql
MySQL-client-5.6.16-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64
MySQL-shared-compat-5.6.16-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64
MySQL-devel-5.6.16-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64
MySQL-shared-5.6.16-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64
MySQL-test-5.6.16-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64
perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64
MySQL-embedded-5.6.16-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64
MySQL-server-5.6.16-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64  and facing same issue on this machine too. I already open a bug on mysql,waiting for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found solution for it .
few things should be remember when using innodb table with memcache plugin.

1. when we create innodb table which are going to used through  memcache, we keep 3 more columns for memcache parameter, like if we want to create a table with 3 column to save our information so we have to keep 3 more columns for memcache plugins so we create table with 6 columns ( 3 to sotre values + 3 column (data type should be integer for c1 and c3 and big int for c2) for make entry in memcache container table ,it is fixed).
2. when we insert records in innodb_memcache.containers ,use these 3 extra column here ,below are details .

Note: 3 extra column named c1,c2,c3 data type should be int.

so we insert records in containers table as below
flags: c1
cas_column: c2
expire_time_column: c3

after setting this now my MySQL doesnot crashed and it is working fine.